# Checking new project over old SVN project

Tags: svn

I have just done some enhancement to a project I worked on a few years ago for a client and I am wondering what is the best way to get it back into SVN. It was in Visual Studio 2010 as an MCV 3 application with a lot of outdated libraries so I decided to create a new project in VS 2013 MVC 5 and copy across the code rather than try and update the old project.

Now I have the new solution with the enhancements can anybody advise me on the best way to get the new project into the old SVN trunk?

Comment: Why weren't you using source control *while* you were developing?

Comment: Copy it back, and commit?

Answer (score 1):

There are two options:

1. Continue the old development line: For this, checkout the old project, merge the changes back, add/remove files necessary and commit
2. Create a new development branch: I would recommend this approach considering it is for a new toolchain. Simply create a new repo/path and add the files.